# Windows Phone 7 2D Game Engine

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, game-engine

Are there any 2D game engines for WP7, that don't use XNA? (I need it because I can't develop with XNA because of my video adapter).

Comment: Let me make sure I understand.  You're abandoning the supported, recommended and preferred gaming engine due to the video adapter on the current development machine you're using?  Doesn't that seem a bit short-sighted?  I would think that in most scenarios, the costs accociated with not using XNA have got to be more than a video adapter.

Comment: I know that XNA is very cool engine, but I'm not ready to buy new netbook now for it.

Comment: Can you run Windows XNA games with a Reach profile? XNA makes it pretty easy to maintain a Windows and a WP7 version at the same time. If you have another (desktop?) machine you could simply do all the WP7-specific work on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Silverlight-based sprite engines...don't count on them to wow your customers.  I'm in agreement with ctatke: upgrade your video card o switch dev machines and get it done properly.

Googling "Silverlight sprite engine" came up with this...might be more if you'd like to dig:

http://slspriteengine.codeplex.com/

Good luck!

-John

Answer (score 0):

These are some XNA Game engine for WP7

http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/

http://www.synapsegaming.com/products/sunburn/engine/

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1801

http://box2dxna.codeplex.com/discussions/224576/

Comment: How does the answer to the question "Are there any 2D game engines for WP7, that don't use XNA?" start with the words "These are some XNA Game engine for WP7"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Reach settings?  It worked for me.  Check here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/07/19/selecting-reach-vs-hidef.aspx

I did, however, notice a list of compatible graphics cards for XNA here: http://www.xnawiki.com/index.php?title=Graphics_card_compatibility

So, if your graphics card is actually supported, then you might try using Reach.